# Opening external links in WKWebView (not externally)

Tags: hyperlink, wkwebview

My app contains HTML information pages opened in WKWebView, containing some hyperlinks. These used to work, but stopped working with recent iOS releases with error messages, containing words

```
Could not create sandbox extension
Connection to daemon was invalidated
```

When I apply WKNavigation delegate with the following code

```
extension InformationPageController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
        var policy =  WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
            //  Neither of commented lines below works! 
            //  webView.load(navigationAction.request)
            //  webView.loadHTMLString(navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteString, baseURL: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
            policy = .cancel
        }
        decisionHandler(policy)
    }
}
```

the pages are opened in an external browser, but not inside the app.

Is there a way to open the links as before, within same WKWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It looks like only `https` protocol is currently accepted by WKWebView. If you have just `http`, WKWebView will complain about insecure protocol and won't open.

After I changed http-s to https-s, the pages opened, but not AppStore pages. This leads to another issue.

2. When URL address starts with `https://apps.apple.com/...`, iOS (but not macOS) redirects it to `itms-appss://apps.apple.com/...`  for opening in AppStore app, causing WKWebView to come up with the error: `Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)`. Similar problem with `mailto` urls.

To bypass these issues I modified code to the following:

```
extension InformationPageController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    static let disallowedUrlPrefixes = ["https://apps.apple.com", "mailto:"]

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {

        var policy =  WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow

        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated,
            let url = navigationAction.request.url {
            let urlString = url.absoluteString
            if InformationPageController.disallowedUrlPrefixes.first(where:{urlString.starts(with: $0)}) != nil {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                policy = .cancel
            }
        }

        decisionHandler(policy)
    }
}
```

Now the 'troublesome' pages are opened with an external browser, all others are opened within WKWebView. Unfortunately that's the best I can currently think of.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because an iOS app by default doesn't allow http requests. Try to allow it by adding "App Transport Security Settings" and add a sub key "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and set it to true in the app's info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```